# How can I detect the first or last page shown by a FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: java, android, fragmentpageradapter

I have a very simple Settings companion app (for a wearable watch face) which uses about 8 swiped pages to set some options from radio buttons. I use individual fragments that I instantiate according to the option chosen.

```
     public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
 ...
         @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a different static fragment depending on which menu item
        // It isn't called if we already have the given fragment available
        if ((position < 0) || (position >= mMenuItems.length)) return null;
        String menu = mMenuItems[position];

        //FIXME: We are setting the existing values when instantiated, which means they may not reflect
        //actual current values when the fragment is displayed
        if (menu.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.period_length))) {
            return PeriodLengthFragment.newInstance(menu, mPeriodLength);
        } else if (menu.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.home_team_color))) {
            return HomeTeamColorFragment.newInstance(menu);
        } else if (menu.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.away_team_color))) {
            return AwayTeamColorFragment.newInstance(menu);
        } else if (menu.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.number_of_periods))) {
            return NumberOfPeriodsFragment.newInstance(menu,mNumberOfPeriods);
        }  else if (menu.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.interval_length))) {
            return IntervalLengthFragment.newInstance(menu, mIntervalLength);
        } else if (menu.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.count_up_or_down))) {
            return CountUpOrDownFragment.newInstance(menu);
        } else if (menu.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.about))) {
            return AboutFragment.newInstance(menu);
        }  else if (menu.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.match_results))) {
            return MatchResultsFragment.newInstance(menu,mHomeTeamScore,mAwayTeamScore );
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I also provide two floating action buttons ("fabs") which you can use instead of swiping and also to provide a visual hint that there are other settings pages:

```
             FloatingActionButton fabPrev = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_previous);
        FloatingActionButton fabNext = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_next);
        //Make the floating action button invisible if it doesn't make sense
        fabPrev.setVisibility(position == 0 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
        fabNext.setVisibility(position == mMenuItems.length-1 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
```

Unfortunately, although I can access `position` in the getItem method (and change the visibility of the fab accordingly), that is called on instantiation of the page, not on display. Because the PagerAdapter instantiates the next and previous page, this leads to the fabs being hidden on the wrong pages.

**Is there any method I can override in the PagerAdapter or FragmentPagerAdapter which is called onCreateView and would give me the position?** One ugly solution is to set the fab visibility in the actual fragments, but that would be brittle in the case if I reorder the position of the first and last pages.

Comment: Why don't you use a OnPageChangeListener with the ViewPager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **setOnPageChangeListener** of the **ViewPager**:

```
    myViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int    positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Check if this is the page you want.
    }
});
```

Comment: In OPs case he can check for `(position == 0 || position == adapter.getItemCount() - 1)`

Comment: Sounds promising! I'll give it a try.

Comment: This worked great (except for the BUT below). I'd note that `setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated and has been replaced by `addOnPageChangeListener` and I used an `OnSimplePageChangeListener` 

The BUT is that `onPageSelected` does not fire when the first page is displayed. I've done some digging and seen an acknowledgement of this problem but no solutions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to my second question (how do you handle the first page), see suggestion buried in here : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27526

The answer is to manually call `onPageSelected` but only after you have set your adapter. My code appears:

```
         // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener vpsopcl = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //Make the floating action button invisible if it doesn't make sense
            fabPrev.setVisibility(position == 0 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
            fabNext.setVisibility(position == mMenuItems.length - 1 ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(vpsopcl);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    //manually call the OnPageSelected to set the buttons on the first page
    vpsopcl.onPageSelected(0);
```